# Connect to server with ppk from console

Tags: ubuntu, sftp, private-key

i am trying to connect ubuntu server using sftp server. But the problem is i have a ppk key and i mustn't convert it to openssh. Is there a way to connect to server using ppk from command line?
This is how i tried.

```
sftp -oIdentityFile=/keys/privatekey.ppk sftpuser@sftpserver
```

Comment: "mustn't convert it to openssh": Why? Also you did not specify what platform you are connecting from.

Comment: so i already accepted Florin Asavoaie's answer.

Comment: I know you did. But his answer ignores this requirement of yours. And I wonder what is a reason for this anyway.

Comment: OK i have a server that act like file sharing service. But its private server so only accepted users can register. Also one application that work on another server to copy all user files to its server and do some process. On first i thought every client will connect with filezilla. In this case i restricted the user right to my server. They only can access its home folders. Anyway i already gave them ppk files to connect server. But in some case (some users doesn't have gui) users using sftp like clients to connect server. But it's not supporting ppk. Problem was there.

Comment: After searching on internet it has no way to get through it but can do it by changing key or convince the clients to use filezilla. I chose first way. Anyway continueing this subject is pointless and he already described the situation so i did accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. OpenSSH does not support the Putty Private Key format. You will have to either convert it to OpenSSH format, either use an SSH Key agent that supports the ppk format, such as the KeeAgent for KeePass.